# Find the minimize of $A=\frac{1}{a^2}\left(b^2+c^2\right)+a^2\left(\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}\right)$

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima

Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $b^2+c^2\le a^2$. Find the minimize of $$A=\frac{1}{a^2}\left(b^2+c^2\right)+a^2\left(\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}\right)$$

---

My try: By AM-GM: $LHS=\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a}+\frac{a^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2}$

$=\frac{a^2}{b^2}+4\frac{b^2}{a}+\frac{a^2}{c^2}+4\frac{c^2}{a^2}-\frac{3\left(b^2+c^2\right)}{a^2}$

$\ge 2\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2}\cdot 4\frac{b^2}{a}}+2\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{c^2}\cdot 4\frac{c^2}{a^2}}-\frac{3\cdot a^2}{a^2}$

$\ge 4+4-3=5$

$"="\Leftrightarrow b=c=\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$

My idea started by the equal occurs when $b=c=\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$ but if I don't know the equal occurs when $b=c=\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$ i can't sol it. Help me sol it.

Comment: For applying AM-GM, having at least a guess at equality conditions is needed, else you have to assume equality at some yet to determined values and work out a lot more. What you’ve done is perfectly fine. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write $b^2+c^2=a^2r^2$, $r\in [0,\,1]$ so $A=r^2+\frac{a^4 r^2}{(bc)^2}$. Write $b=arC,\,c=arS$ with $C=\cos t,\,S=\sin t$ (say) so $A=r^2+\frac{1}{r^2 C^2 S^2}\ge r^2+\frac{4}{r^2}$, with equality iff $\sin 2t=\pm 1,\,C^2=S^2=\frac{1}{2}$. Since $\frac{d}{dr}(r^2+\frac{4}{r^2})=2r(1-\frac{4}{r^4})<0$ for $r\in [0,\,1]$, we obtain the minimum at $r=1$. Thus $A$ has minimum $5$, obtained with $b^2=c^2=\frac{a^2}{2}$ as you thought.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: we get
$$\frac{1}{a^2}(b^2+c^2)+a^2\left(\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}\right)\geq 5$$
The equal sign holds, if
$$a=1,b=c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

The first thing, which we need to check, when we want to prove inequality it's to check the equality case, which you made. It says that your solution is beautiful!

Comment: Oh thank you Michael.